# Query Cassandra Mviews from Prestodb

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, presto, datastax-startup

I am unable to query cassandra mview from prestodb. 
It gives below error. 
presto> select * from mykeyspace1.mymview1 where phone in ('1234567890'); 
*Query 20170213_131643_00074_5smf2 failed: line 1:15: Table cassandra.mykeyspace1.mymview1 does not exist*

I have DSE 5.0.4 installed.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.166, Presto does not support Cassandra materialized views. Please file an issue in the Presto repo: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues. If you want to take a shot at fixing it, we can give you pointers in the issue.

Comment: we use Presto 0.158. If its an issue with this version too, I will file the issue in https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues.

Comment: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7363 - Opened an issue.  Can you pl. help with pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: Sure, I'll comment on the issue.